# find longest contiguous sequence in a multiple sets of integers

Tags: algorithm

I am trying to figure out an efficient way to find the longest sequence of integers among a group of integer sets.

e.g.

```
Set 1 = { 100, 200, 300, 400, 500 }
Set 2 = { A, B, 100, 200, 300, 400 ,Z}
Set 3 = { 200, 300, 400 }

the answer should be { 200, 300, 400 }
```

Is SuffiX tree an option, or is there a simpler approach.

Comment: You mean the longest common contiguous subset of integers, right?

Comment: @smttsp yes.. that's correct.

Comment: You might wanne have a look here, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem. That uses a suffix tree if  I am correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the best option available for your problem, for more clarification:

- Here is a good article on [Suffix tree](http://www.drdobbs.com/architecture-and-design/algorithm-alley/184404588) with a detailed implementation in C.